# SQL Server pivot average

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sum, pivot, average

I have a Microsoft SQL server pivot query that gets a sum of values with rows per category and monthly columns 1 to 12

I currently have 13 columns returned in the query, for example, with no data after april:

```
 Category  [1]   [2]   [3]   [4]   [5]   [6]   [7]   [8]   [9]   [10]   [11]   [12]
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Food      150   200   0     125   null  null  null  null  null  null   null   null  
 Drink     140    0     90   115   null  null  null  null  null  null   null   null
```

Per category, I need to add the total sum of values, as well as the average value ignoring months with no data.
For the data above, I need to add the columns:

```
 Sum   Average
 475    118.75
 345     86.25
```

I tried many different methods, but I couldn't find a way.

Comment: Can you post your original query, table structure and some sample data?  There might be a few ways to do this and seeing this info would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this query?

```
Select *
From
(
    Select ItemName as Itm, [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12] 
    From
    (
        Select ItemName, Month(EffectiveDate) as Mon, Val
            From Items

    ) as SourceTable
    Pivot
    (
        Sum(Val)
        For Mon in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
    ) as PivotTable
) A
Cross Apply (Select SUM(Val) as SumVal, AVG(Val) as AvgVal From Items i Where i.ItemName = a.Itm) b
```

See the pic:

http://s18.postimage.org/lwbovyy49/results.jpg

Comment: Thanks, this is a clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

I know this looks stupid, but it will do the trick. :-)

```
Select Category,(isnull(f1,0)+isnull(f2,0)+isnull(f3,0)) as sumall,
isnull((isnull(f1,0)+isnull(f2,0)+isnull(f3,0)),1)/isnull(nullif((0+(isnull(nullif(isnull(f1,isnull(f1,0)),f1),1))+(isnull(nullif(isnull(f2,isnull(f2,0)),f2),1))+(isnull(nullif(isnull(f3,isnull(f3,0)),f3),1))),0),1) as avr
from MyTable
```

Comment: Oh no!! :p. That is too much !!

Comment: Sorry, my example is only for 3 "months". copy/paste all the f-fields to match 12 month. :-)